# Botframework Loop inside of AdaptiveCard C#

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I want to create a loop in side adaptive card body for adaptivecardcontainer. I have refereed the below solution but issue is i have to add loop to container inside the body, so how to access the container to add my textblock code.
[C# Botframework Loop inside of AdaptiveCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046755/c-sharp-botframework-loop-inside-of-adaptivecard)
I have to add for loop at below possition.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create list of Adaptive TextBlocks first and then assign it at appropriate position.

```
                var textBlocks = new List<AdaptiveElement>();
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    textBlocks.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Textblock" + i });
                }

                var adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCard("1.0")
                {
                    Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                    {
                        new AdaptiveContainer
                        {
                            Items=textBlocks
                        }
                    }

                };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq. Something like:

```
myList.Select(item => new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
    Text = myList.text,
    ...
}).ToList(),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at AdaptiveCard templating.
Its a ton easier than what you are trying there including for loops etc.

With templating you just write the json code for the card and bind your data to it. No need to create all those classes and c# loops...easier to handle and performance is better.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/

Comment: https://medium.com/@tim.cadenbach/why-templating-for-adaptive-cards-is-a-game-changer-1606de3226ed i pretty much explained a really similar scenario to yours here